# ALAssetsLibrary returning nil for asset that has HEIC URL

Tags: swift, alassetslibrary, heif

I'm using ALAssetsLibrary to grab an image using its assets library URL. This works fine if the image is a jpeg. However, if I try and grab one that is an HEIF, the call returns nil for the asset. I know that I will need to convert to using PHPhotoLibrary at some point but I'm not quite ready for that yet. Anybody ever seen this problem and/or know how to get around it? Is ALAssetsLibrary just not compatible with HEIF? Here's some code:

```
let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
// url is set elsewhere
library.asset(for: url, resultBlock: { (asset) in
    // asset is nil here if I pass in an HEIC url, fine if it is JPEG
    // "assets-library://asset/asset.HEIC?id=070FBF77-869D-4B3D-840A-74B4FC65648D&ext=HEIC"
}, failureBlock: { (error) in 
    // Handle error
})
```

Comment: The old ALAssetsLibrary was deprecated back in iOS 9. Try using the newer Photos library.

Comment: I know that's where I'll end up ultimately but I'm trying to get a release out now.

Comment: Since HEIC is a new format added in iOS 11 and since the old assets library was replaced in iOS 8, it's unlikely you will be able to make it work for such files with an old and out-of-date library.